# rsync by path/filename only?

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, rsync

Is there a way for me to rsync two directories comparing only filenames (and not file size, date modified, or any other criteria)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the `rsync(1)` man page:

```
        --ignore-existing       skip updating files that exist on receiver
```

Comment: Really speeds things up when syncing large files from or to an underpowered machine (as fingerprinting is pretty computational heavy).